# Import big csv in Laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using following package to import large CSV file to MySQL database:

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Here is my controller code:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file)->chunk(250, function($results) use ($count)
    {
        ++$count;

        echo "<br/> Count = " . $count;

        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Here is line from composer.json

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
```

Here is my config/app.php file:

```
'providers' => [
 ....
 ....
 Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
 ],

 'aliases' => [
 ....
 ....
 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
 ]
```

I am getting this error and I cannot find any solution:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Dispatcher.php line 333:
No handler registered for command [Maatwebsite\Excel\Readers\ChunkedReadJob]
```

I tried following link for solution but no luck:

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/957

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/952

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing some manipulations for each row of csv before inserting into the database or is it like you need to import the data directly to the database?

Just a quick tip, its your csv is in the sequence how your database table columns are ordered, you can use ubuntu terminal to import larger files :

```
mysql -uroot -proot --local_infile=1 3parsfdb -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/logfiles/Bat_res.csv' INTO TABLE Bat_res FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
```

If this is something which you want to do programatically or in cron, then you need this package. Can you try clearing laravel cache and also try

composer dump-autoload

One more thing is to ensure there are no special characters in the csv which can not get imported.

Comment: Okay let me check the github files quickly.

Comment: Can you try any off following :  Change "class ChunkedReadJob implements ShouldQueue" to "class ChunkedReadJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue" or to "class ChunkedReadJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue, SelfHandling"

Comment: Also check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208519/laravel-5-command-and-handler-issue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that package, try the LOAD DATA INFILE MySQL procedure, using Laravel's  DB object. Here is an [example](https://tenerant.com/blog/using-load-data-local-infile-in-a-laravel-migration/).
I used this for importing big sized csv files (300M-400M) into a mysql db and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE! I really missed MySQL, I used this to ingest a huge CVS file, about 6gb in our server, this took about 20 mins.

You can use something like this:

```
private function importData(int $ignoreLines, string $fileName) : void
{
    //$this->setLOG("Importing data, please wait", "i");
    $table = 'npdata_csvfile_temp';

    $importDB  = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fileName' ";
    $importDB .= "INTO TABLE $table ";
    $importDB .= "COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ";
    $importDB .= 'OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "\""';
    $importDB .= "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ";
    $importDB .= "IGNORE $ignoreLines LINES ";

    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($importDB);
    //$this->setLOG("Done with importing data", "i");
}
```